# unlimited zero as output while running c++ in cpp driod

Tags: c++

```
for (short i = 1; i < 5; i++)
    for (j = 0; j > 0; j--)
        cout << i << "\t";
```

Anybody please answer the above code.. i am getting continuous zero why is it so please explain

Comment: where is `j` declared?

Comment: when i run this, it prints nothing because `j`  is never greater then 0.

Comment: sorry it is j=5 as initialised

Comment: Well, with optimization off, j will eventually underflow..

Comment: @Rag where is `j` initialized as five? i only see it set as 5.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you need to declare the variable j somewhere. Assuming you have declared j somewhere else in the program, this program as you have written it here will actually print nothing out.

Since j is set to start at 0, and 0 is not greater than 0, the

```
cout<<i<<"\t";
```

line will never actually be run. If you could provide more of your code we may be able to answer your question better. You could try setting j to start at 1 if you want it to actually print out i.

Answer (score 0):

[Link to Online IDE running the program](http://goo.gl/VIDuq0)

On executing the program, there is no output.

> `for(short i=1;i<5;i++)`

This statement declares and initializes the variable i to 1, checks if it is less than 5 and then moves on to the next statement

> `for(j=0;j>0;j--)`

This statement initializes j to 0 (Note that j has to be declared previously), and then checks if j is greater than 0. As j isn't greater than 0, it doesn't move on to the next statement, i.e. `cout<<i<<"\t";` and continues the previous loop, the loop with the variable `i`.

The `i`- loop runs 4 times, and since anything isn't actually printed to the screen, you don't get any output.

Answer (score 0):

First this code won't compile as you have not defined j. After you do that, it wont print anything as j is never greater than 0.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    for(short i=1;i<5;i++)
    for(short j=0;j>0;j--)
    std::cout<<i<<"\t";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (j = 0; j > 0; j--)
```

This is a zero iteration loop. Initializes `j` to `0` checks if `j` is greater than `0`.

Answer (score 0):

1) If j=0, the loop undergoes 0 iterations and hence no output.

2) If j=5, you get each of the numbers from 1 to 5 printed 5 times as output.

1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5